# Hide and Show list on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to hide and show a list from a certain point. But it is not working. I am using jquery .toggle to be able to get this effect but for some reason the list items wont budge. Really need an explanation on this and why it isnt working.

**CSS**:

```css
div#right-column-sidebar{position: absolute; top: 840px; right: -140px}

div#right-column-sidebar ol{position:absolute; right: 150px;margin:    
10px 0 10px 10px; font-size: 20px; color: red;list-style-type:none}

div#right-column-sidebar ol li {list-style-type:none;margin: 10px 0 10px 0; border-    
bottom: 1px dotted grey; width: 200px; display: block;}}

div#right-column-sidebar ol li a{font-size: 60%; color: blue;margin-left: 20px}
div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(11){margin-left:}      
div#right-column-sidebar ol li a:hover{text-decoration: underline;}

a.button {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;no-repeat scroll top right;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
    height: 24px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.button span {
    display: block;
    line-height: 14px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 18px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="right-column-sidebar">
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">Title 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Title 20</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
<a class="button" href="#"><span>Show more</span></a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$('a.button').click( function() { 
    $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(1n)').toggle(); 
});
```

That's all the code and I want to hide and show the list items from a point and further down. And again I want to show them when I click again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/9HXzW/1/

```
$('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(4)').hide();
$('a.button').on("click", function() {
    $('div#right-column-sidebar ol li:gt(4)').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know about the `gt()` pseudo selector!

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zn55e/1/. My guess is that you're either not loading jQuery correctly or you weirded yourself out by specifying `nth-child(1n)` in the Javascript - if you're going for the first item, `nth-child(1)` is the correct parlance.

PS: close the `margin-left` line at `div#right-column-sidebar ol li:nth-child(11){margin-left:`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/nickaknudson/fkqgz/